# How to pass a result when calling CancelAllDialogsAsync in bot framework?

Tags: c#, botframework

We have been using the bot framework for a while now and are very happy with it. We use the `stepContext.Parent.CancelAllDialogsAsync()` method. This works fine but we want to pass a result or trigger some kind of action in the bot code. We would like to pass a value.

I noticed the optional `eventName` and `eventValue` parameters, but I cannot find any way to use them. I found this documentation for the method but the `eventName` and `eventValue` are not explained at all. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialogcontext.cancelalldialogsasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable.

I thought that it would trigger the DialogBot's `OnEventActivityAsync` method, but it doesn't.

Our use case is as follows: At some point in the conversation our bot asks the user a question. When the user doesn't answer the question multiple times, but instead keeps asking their own question we call `CancelAllDialogsAsync`. The bot will get back to the MainDialog and wait for user input, so the user will have to ask their question again. We don't want the user to have to ask agian, so we want to cancel all dialogs and go back to the MainDialog passing the users question so the MainDialog can pick a way to answer it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the back end? What part of your code do you want to have receive the result? Do you need a result because you're calling `CancelAllDialogsAsync` from multiple places and you want some root functionality to know where it was called from? Can you provide some sample code that illustrates how you've set up your bot?

Comment: At some point in the conversation our bot asks the user a question. When the user doesn't answer the question multiple times, but instead keeps asking their own question we call `CancelAllDialogsAsync `. So the bot will get back to the MainDialog to answer the users question. But when we do this the bot waits for user input, so the user will have to ask their question again. So we want to cancel all dialogs and go back to the MainDialog passing the users question so the MainDialog can pick a way to answer it.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It sounds like you just need the utterance found in the incoming activity, rather than any dialog-specific information. If that's the case, doesn't that mean you don't actually need to pass a result when calling `CancelAllDialogsAsync`? Won't your main dialog still have access to the same turn context with the same incoming activity? In case there's any confusion about how dialogs work, I highly recommend reviewing the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog

Comment: I see what you mean, but there still needs to be some way to identify that all dialogs were canceled, or the main dialog would be answering the wrong question while doing its regular loop. My college got it working by starting the main dialog right after the `CancelAllDialogsAsync` call and passing the utterance as part of the options.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. Are you saying your issue has been resolved? Would you like to post that as an answer? If you'd like an answer from me, I still need to see some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution is to store the utterance in the user state.
The MainDialog checks the userstate if an utterance is stored. If so it will answer it. No utterance is stored in the user state the main dialog it will ask the user 'What can I do for you?'.

Comment: If you check your dialog state after a few iterations of this, you may find that your state is growing like a sort of memory leak. This would be because you've set up recursive dialogs by beginning a new instance of the main dialog as a leaf node on the stack instead of going back to the original instance of the main dialog by ending the other dialogs. Since you seem to be using component dialogs, this can result in deep nesting which can break Cosmos DB if that's what you're using to store your dialog state.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have any suggestions to fix this? Where do I find the stack of dialogs (in the step context somewhere)?